# rsync: backup directory locally before syncing from remote

Tags: rsync

I have a code base on my production server which is synced from a remote directory. One thing I want to improve about the rsync process is to make it make a local copy first before it takes place and over write the original files. Something like

```
before syncing files from remote :
cp -rf production_code_base production_code_base_old
now syncing remote changes to the production directory
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

besides the `--backup-dir` option (which i haven't used, so i'm not sure if it's appropriate), you could do a 'hard link backup' with `cp -al production_code_base production_code_base_old`.  I'ts *very* fast since it doesn't copy the data, and it doesn't use up space for unchanged files.

**Note:** This is safe in this specific case because `rsync` never opens an existing file for writing, it writes everything to temporary files and finishes with a `mv` after that.  Other transfer systems might overwrite existing files, destroying the hard-link 'backup'.

Comment: "Never" unless you give it the `--inplace` flag. Rsync is very flexible. :)

Comment: @mattdm: you're right, of course.  rsync can do almost anything, including shooting your own foot.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's lots of ways to do that. Like, the `cp` command you just posted. Or you can use the `--backup-dir` option to rsync.

But what are you trying to accomplish? Might it better be done with proper version control?

Comment: I'm using rsync for code deployment. In case there is something going wrong with the new code. I need to backup the previous code first. The code is actually version controlled by the GIT tool. But we don't want to put the .git/ stuff to production along with the real code.

Comment: But, isn't the previous code also already in git?